# changing JavaScript with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need a button to change it's URL to match that of the iframe that is presented on the screen the problem I face here is how can I change the URL of the button with JavaScript?

Here is what I have as of now:

```
   <button id="t7"onclick="t7()">Full Pilot</button><br>
    function f0() {document.getElementById('i').src="https://pilot.wright.edu/d2l/home";}
  function f1() {document.getElementById('i').src="https://pilot.wright.edu/d2l/home/159483";}
    function f2() {document.getElementById('i').src="https://pilot.wright.edu/d2l/le/content/219408/Home";}
   function f3() {document.getElementById('i').src="https://pilot.wright.edu/d2l/home/159465";}
   function f4() {document.getElementById('i').src="https://pilot.wright.edu/d2l/home/219301";}
    function f5() {document.getElementById('i').src="https://pilot.wright.edu/d2l/home/159463";}
```

the functions f0 - f5 are the buttons that I need to have change the URL of the button listed at very first line of code. can any one point me in the direction of which I can do this or even some ideas as to how I can go about doing this.

Here is one thing I have tried:

```
    function t7() {window.open("document.getElementById("i").src="");}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far, and post a demo to reproduce your particular issue?

Comment: the problem is I have very little idea of how to even attempt this.

Comment: Then you probably need to do some more research. We expect code in questions asking for code. Try the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) for general JavaScript knowledge. Also see [how to write a good question](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) when you got some code, you're half way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, button should have "type" attributes, Different browsers may have different default value for button element.

second, button don't have src attribute, so you can't change the src of the button, try using `<a>` instead.

third, iframe support onload event, which will be fired after the iframe is loaded.

so this is probably what you want

```
<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com" onload="iload(this)"></iframe>
<a href="#" id="t7">Full Pivot</a>
<script>
    function iload(obj) {
       document.getElementById("t7").href = obj.src;
    }
</script>
```

UPDATE: no href method

```
<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com" onload="iload(this)"></iframe>
<button type="button" id="t7">Full Pivot</a>
<script>
    function iload(obj) {
        document.getElementById("t7").onclick = function() {
            window.location.href=obj.src;
        }
    }
</script>
```

alternatively, a shorter approach.

```
<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com" id="the_iframe"></iframe>
<button type="button" onclick="iload">Full Pivot</a>
<script>
    function iload() {
        window.location.href=document.getElementById("the_iframe").src;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: okay, well I would like a bit of clarification on the object.src and I am trying to avoid using hyperlinks | prefer buttons

Comment: @CMS2 I've edited the answer, please take a look. About the `obj.src`, the `iload(this)` will parse the iframe object into the obj variable. So when you call `obj.src` it will return the `src` of the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.getElementById('t7').onclick="...";` to change the "url."

Comment: okay so I have tried using this just now but it still sets the src to the file path instead of the URL that it is showing

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:
   first button press:

```
function f0(){document.getElementById('i').src="https://pilot.wright.edu/d2l/home";document.getElementById('o').innerHTML="https://pilot.wright.edu/d2l/home"}
```

HTML:

```
   <p id="o">https://pilot.wright.edu/d2l/home</p>
```

solution:

```
function t7() {window.open(document.getElementById('o').innerHTML);}
```

I basically just added a paragraph node and shared the URL to the button's innerHTML

Thank you to all who answered